# Drawer, Fragment and Activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-navigation

I have some questions about designing applications with `NavigationDrawer`.

I create an application with `NavigationDrawer` composed of one `Activity` and some `Fragment`s. For example I have four `Fragment`s, and every `Fragment` has some actions.

Which is the correct way to implement that?

1. Adding all actions to my `Activity`?
2. Create some other classes and call them from `MainActivity` with context/view?
3. Other?

Any information about these questions is really appreciated. I also need some example or resource explaining which is the correct way to implement this.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Check the google IO 2014 source code to get a good idea of the nav drawer implementation

https://github.com/google/iosched

All the navigation and fragment transactions should be done via the  Main Activity or the activity holding the fragments. Any kind of fragment - fragment communication should be avoided. The developer docs shows a good example  of how to handle fragment communication via Activity using interfaces

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html